# How do I disable the image toolbar for images in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

When hovering the mouse over images IE pops up a little toolbar that suggests saving, printing and so on.

Here's a pic of this:

[image]

**I need to accomplish this with JavaScript**.

Answer (score 4):

This only works if the image is embedded in a web page.

If you do NOT want an image to show the toolbar, then use GALLERYIMG="no" in the img tag.

If you DO want an image to show the toolbar, then use GALLERYIMG="yes" in the img tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533774(VS.85).aspx

Comment: According to the page you linked to, that attribute is obsolete.

Comment: [Cavaet: I don't have IE7 installed] A websearch tells me that IE7 does not have a toolbar, so its no longer a problem as it was in IE6. Your comment about the attribute now being obsolete in IE7 is thus indeed correct.

Comment: This is the only way to do it.  You can't do it in Javascript.  If the GALLERYIMG attribute isn't present at DocumentComplete, it won't be processed.  The tag is obsolete because this feature was removed in IE7.  As the developer who both implemented it and removed it, I apologize.  I was an intern, and I implemented what was in the spec.  I promise to never do it again.

Comment: Oh, alternatively you can insert the img dynamically after DocumentComplete fires and then the code won't know about the img.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
```

[(Source)](http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/turning-off-the-internet-explorer-image-toolbar.1421.html)