# how to disable the image toolbar

Tags: javascript

How can I disable the image toolbar that popups whenever mouse pointer is over an image. I need to do this within javascript only.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886452/how-do-i-disable-the-image-toolbar-for-images-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

The image toolbar can be disabled through a meta tag:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="imagetoolbar" CONTENT="no">
```

or apparently (though I haven't tried this) using an attribute on the tag itself:

```
GALLERYIMG="no"
```

The latter approach could obviously be done in a pure Javascript solution...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
```

or for an individual image:

```
<img src="imageurl.png" galleryimg="no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the image as a background element through CSS instead of using img tag. The tag will probably always have the popup.